# « des vraies réponses » au lieu de « de vraies réponses »

Tags: grammaire

> J’ai encore quelques questions, et je veux des réponses. **Des** vraies réponses.

Pourquoi faut-il utiliser « des » au lieu de « de » ici ? Ou se pourrait-il que les deux soient possibles ?

Comment: Les deux sont possible, **de** s'utilise quand tu ne quantifie pas et **des** quand c'est quantifiable. Selon le sens voulu de ou des peuvent tous les deux s'utiliser dans ce cas.

Comment: J'aurais utilisé ***De*** personnellement. Ou alors `J’ai encore quelques questions, et je veux des réponses, des vraies.`

Comment: Pour ma part, j'utiliserais "de" comme dans la question, mais si j'utilisais "des", alors j'inverserais "réponses" et "vraies": "De vraies réponses", "Des réponses vraies", mais pour mettre l'accent sur la véracité, plutôt que sur les réponses, alors la proposition de @YohannV. est appropriée.

Comment: @MorganFR Je suis on ne peut plus d'accord. Raison de plus pour me demander pourquoi la locutrice penche pour "**des**". Comme évoqué par  Yohann V, est-ce qu'au début elle ne comptait pas y ajouter "**réponses**" mais a fini par le faire  tout de même, peut-être sur un coup de tête ? Merci.

Comment: Vous n'avez évoqué aucun contexte. Pour ma part, je pensais que vous nous posiez la question selon ce que vous pensiez. Si cette phrase a un contexte particulier ou une source, mieux vaut faire part du plus d'information possible dans la question, afin d'y répondre au mieux.

Comment: @MorganFR Hi. This comes from an email that one of my colleagues received from another French speaker, so there is not much to offer in terms of context, unfortunately.

Comment: It sounds weird to me, I would say it was a clumsy way of saying it, regardless of the fact that she mixed up a couple different ways of saying it or just thought this was good enough. Either way, you should be fine with the three alternatives we provided.

Comment: Des vraies réponses is: real answers, des réponses vrais: true answers meaning ones that are not false. In English, true answers can mean real answers too. de vraies réponses would mean: about real answers or of real answers. Je voudrais des vraies réponses; I would like real answers.

Comment: Pour moi la différence porte sur ce qu'on attend exactement. Avec "je veux des vraies réponses" on insiste sur "réponses": on demande avant tout à avoir des réponses, et on veut en second lieu qu'elles soient vraies (ce qui est un peu bizarre, c'est pourquoi on voir rarement cela). Avec "je veux de vraies réponses" on demande à ce que les réponse qu'on nous fournisse soient vraies, probablement parce qu'on a auparavant reçu des réponses qui n'en étaient pas vraiment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalement, on dit "De vraies réponses" et "Des réponses vraies" ; "Des vraies réponses" ne me semble pas correct. [Cette page](http://www.gabrielwyler.com/page022.html#Articleind%C3%A9finipluriel(des)) donne une explication :

> L'épithète descriptive a une forte tendance à déclencher la réduction à de.
>
> La tendance de l'épithète restrictive à déclencher la réduction à de est faible.
>
> Comme les adjectifs qui précèdent le nom sont souvent descriptifs, la réduction est en forte corrélation avec la position de l'adjectif.

[Cette page](http://www.gabrielwyler.com/page027.html#Restrictivit%C3%A9etdescriptivit%C3%A9del%27%C3%A9pith%C3%A8te) permet de comprendre la notion de descriptivité et restrictivité. Dans le cas qui nous intéresse, c'est assez difficile de percevoir la nuance, car l'emphase due à la répétition du mot "réponse" incite à comprendre l'adjectif "vrai" comme un critère nécessaire : on exige que les réponses soient vraies, ça ressemble donc à une restriction. Faute de règle précise, je suppose que la grammaire ne se soucie pas de ce contexte et que dans notre cas ("De vraies réponses"), "vrai" reste descriptif. Si l'on sort de ce contexte d'emphase, on distingue mieux la nuance entre les deux positions de "vrai" :

> Il a obtenu de vraies réponses. (= il a obtenu des réponses qui se trouvent être correctes -> descriptif)
>
> Il a obtenu des réponses vraies. (= parmi toutes les réponses qu'il aurait pu obtenir, il a obtenu celles correctes -> restrictif)